# Android Download Manager class name issue on Samsung S6

Tags: android, android-download-manager

My app downloads pdf files from links on button click.
I am using download manager and it is working great on ALL DEVICES except Samsung S6!

Here is a sample code

```
private boolean isDownloadManagerAvailable() {
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.providers.downloads.ui", "com.android.providers.downloads.ui.DownloadList");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Samsung S6 debugging shows that list.size() is actually 0 (ONLY ON S6). And i cannot find any alternative for the classes I am using, as all other devices work perfectly.
I do not know if samsung has changed the classes in S6?!

Thanks.

Comment: What is the android version of this device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Turns out samsung S6 does not have these classes and thus is returning 0.
Returning true and ignoring this check did the job.
The application i was updating was many years old code.
I guess no need for the check anymore.